# Show/hide an HTML element: better set Bootstrap 4's [hidden] attribute or call jQuery's .hide() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using Bootstrap 4, as well as jQuery 3.1.1

I want to hide elements when a `select` val changes. What is the best solution? Add the Bootstrap's [hidden] element (see [Bootstrap: Migration to v4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#responsive-utilities)) or call jQuery's .hide() function (see [jQuery's .hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/))?

```
var select = $("select[name=whatever]");
if (select.length) {
  select.change(function() {
    if (select.val() > 0) {
      $("input[name=foobar]"); // TODO Hide this element
    } else {
      $("input[name=foobar]"); // TODO Show this element
    }
  });
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `.toggle()` i.e.`$("input[name=foobar]").toggle(this.value > 0);`

Comment: Use jQuery .hide()

Comment: `select.change(function () {
    $("input[name=foobar]").toggle(!this.value.length);
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your check that the element exists is redundant as jQuery is tolerant of calling a method on a selector that contains no elements. You also appears to be missing some quotes in your code, but I assume that's just a typo in the question.

Secondly, the `value` of the element is provided as a string, so you'll need to parse it to an integer otherwise you may get some odd results when the type is coerced.

From there you can simply call `hide()` and `show()`:

```
var $select = $('select[name="whatever"]').change(function() {
    if (parseInt(this.value, 10) > 0) {
        $('input[name="foobar"]').hide()
    } else {
        $('input[name="foobar"]').show();
    }
}
```

You could also make this logic more succinct by using `toggle()` only, with a state flag to set the visibility of the element:

```
var $select = $('select[name="whatever"]').change(function() {
    $('input[name="foobar"]').toggle(parseInt(this.value, 10) <= 0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer.
What do you mean by _missing some quotes_? I miss the closing one for ``$("input[name=foobar]);`` but for ``$("select[name=whatever]");`` this works. It doesn't appear to be mandatory: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors
Also I have no issue with the comparison, because all the possible values for the ``select`` are Long in Java. e.g. when ``select.val()`` evaluates to ``"2017"``, ``select.val() > 0`` evaluates to ``true``.

Comment: I meant that you were missing the closing quote on the selector. I also wrapped the actual attribute value in quotes just as it saves any issues where the value may contain spaces of special characters. I'd still suggest you explicitly convert types, regardless of the string value.